# How might an estimate of the Stellar network's energy consumption be measured and monitored?

Tags: stellar-laboratory

I'd like to estimate the emissions footprint of the Stellar network in an effort to compare various networks with one another. I realize this can a complex calculation depending upon where one starts and stops, so correlations with say number of transactions might be a useful way of thinking about this. Lastly, are there tools/prototypes we might build to monitor and thereby aim to optimize?

Answer (score 1):

i think your best bet is to figure out how other networks are measuring their emissions and mimicking their model / implementation.